# ¿como puedo verificar un patron en Ruby?, ya tengo un elsif para un regex pero no se como hacer para patrones

Tags: ruby

este es mi bloque de codigo del metodo my_none? que pretende simular al metodo none? de ruby

```
def my_none?(arg = false)
    if block_given?
      my_each { |x| return false if yield(x) == true }
      return true
    elsif arg.nil?
      my_each { |i| return true if i.nil? || i == false }
    elsif arg.is_a?(Regexp)
      my_each { |x| return false unless x.match(arg) }
    else
      my_each { |i| return false if i == true }
    end
    true
  end
```

este es el metodo my_each

```
def my_each
    return to_enum unless block_given?

    for i in self
      yield i
    end
  end
```

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F esta es la documentacion que estoy siguiendo y esto lo que falta testear %w{ant bear cat}.none?(/d/)  que debe devolver true

Comment: ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de ejecución completo para tu código? porque no me funciona para los casos ya implementados. Probé en mi consola con `my_none? nil` y me arrojó `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for main:Object`, presumo en el `for i in self`. Y recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta, no es necesario que agregues info extra como comentario. Saludos

Comment: Si estás implementando `my_each` y `my_none`, entiendo que estás aprendiendo Ruby por primera vez. Te aconsejo que escribas tests para estos métodos, y los compartas con nosotros. Te ayudarán a comprender mejor lo qué está pasando, y a nosotros a ayudarte.